# drag and drop programmatically generated UIButtons

Tags: iphone, drag-and-drop, uibutton

I created many uibuttons dynamically via a for loop and added them to the scene. Now I want to add drag and drop capability to each uibutton. How can I accomplish this?

Say a game like breaker, you have a paddle. It is the only object which will be dragged and dropped by player so all we need to do is add a uibutton object for the paddle and update its center in touchesBegan and touchesMoved.

In my problem, I don't know which button will be clicked. If I attached an action to all the buttons to track which button being click then I won't be able to perform DRAG the first time player click on a button. Maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I don't understand, but each button should "know" if it is the one being clicked. In the `touchesMoved:withEvent:` method, couldn't you just set the center to the location of the touch, or is there something I'm missing?

Try this.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (self.highlighted) {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        self.center = CGPointMake(touch.x, touch.y);
    }
}
```

Of course, this code has a couple issues such as not dealing well with multiple touches, but I hope it gets the point across.
If you just want to be able to tell which button is currently tapped, you can use the `highlighted` property of UIControl. Hope that helps!

Comment: I didn't know that each button should know if its the one being clicked. Can please you write the code to accomplish this? Thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer appropriately. I haven't done much work with touchesBegan: and the like, so it may not be as specific as you want.

Comment: it doesn't work. i got error "Request for member 'highlighted' in something not a structure or union".

Comment: Are you subclassing UIButton?

Comment: no, i just copied your code and replace my touchesMoved. Sorry, I'm very new to iphone programming and objective -c

Comment: the main view controller class. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok heres the problem: the idea behind touchesMoved:withEvent: is that it is a method of UIView that you should be overriding. Create a new file, say "MyButton" and have it be a subclass of UIButton. Tell me how that works.